# Command 'sbt assembly' taking long to build Spark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have just installed the pyspark in my pc. I have used the command 'sbt assembly' to build it but it's showing some progress for more than an hour in the terminal but didn't complete the process.

Answer (score 0):

Be patient spark take much time to compile and build source manually.